# error :- "detail": "Not Found" using Fastapi with Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, fastapi

Hi My fastapi code works well in VS code.
I am planning to use my code using Azure Function app.
I am following this block where they have used ASGI method.
https://medium.com/fastapi-tutorials/serverless-fastapi-on-azure-cddf8cd50482
I am getting below error

{
"detail": "Not Found"
}

```
import azure.functions as func
from .http_asgi import AsgiMiddleware
import fastapi

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

@app.get("/{user_id}")
async def get_user(user_id: int):
    return "Hello"


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use fast api in azure functions you need to make few changes in the azure function code according to the fast api there are few independent and dependent changes, Below is the sample code to import Fast API into functions.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import logging

app = FastAPI(title="Azure Function to FastAPI migration",debug=True)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

@app.post("/fast_api_test/", status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK)
def fast_api_test(req_body: dict):
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return {"Hello, " + str(name)+". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."}
    else:
        return {"This HTTP triggered function e
```

Make the changes in your code which will help you in resolving the issues.

Here is the complete [document](https://iotespresso.com/azure-function-to-fastapi-app-service/) on importing Fast API with functions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out configuration of *host.json* file in the root of the project.

Mine after creation was lacking lines

```
...
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
```

Also make sure *function.json* config of your function has routing parameter set

```
...
      "route": "/{*route}"
...
```